# remove all data attributes with etree from all elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, lxml, elementtree

So I'm attempting to clean some HTML. I've got the following function:

```
def clean_html(self, html):
    replaced_html = html.decode('utf-8').replace('<', ' <')

    tree = etree.HTML(replaced_html)
    etree.strip_elements(tree, 'script', 'style', 'img', 'noscript', 'svg')

    for el in tree.xpath('//*[@style]'):
        el.attrib.pop('style')

    for el in tree.xpath('//*[@class]'):
        el.attrib.pop('class')

    for el in tree.xpath('//*[@id]'):
        el.attrib.pop('id')

    etree.strip_tags(tree, etree.Comment)
    return etree.tostring(tree, encoding='unicode', method='html')
```

I'm looking to also remove all `data-attributes` e.g

```
<li data-direction="ltr" '
         'data-listposition="center" data-data-id="dataItem-ifz7cqbs" '
         'data-state="menu idle link notMobile">sky</li>
```

But the attributes are unknown to me (above is just an example).

So I'm looking to transform the above into just `<li>sky</li>` and would run on every element on the page.

In my code above I'm able to remove simple things like `id`, `class` but I'm not sure how to handle the dynamic attributes `data-*`. Possibly regex?

### EDIT

I should clarify a bit about the input. My example above shows the use of `<li>` tags. But the actual input is the entire html of a page so it would be something like:

```
<html>
  <ul>
    <li data-i="sdfdsf">something</li>
    <li data-i="dsfd">something</li>
  </ul>
  <p data-para="cvcv">content</p>
 <div data-image-info='{"imageData":{"type":"Image","id":"dataItem-ifp35za1","metaData":{"pageId":"masterPage","isPreset":false,"schemaVersion":"2.0","isHidden":false},"title":"Black LinkedIn Icon","uri":"6ea5b4a88f0b4f91945b40499aa0af00.png","width":200,"height":200,"alt":"Black LinkedIn Icon","link":{"type":"ExternalLink","id":"dataItem-ig84dp5v","metaData":{"pageId":"masterPage","isPreset":false,"schemaVersion":"1.0","isHidden":false},"url":"https://www.linkedin.com/in/beth-liu-aba2b487?trk=hp-identity-name","target":"_blank"}},"displayMode":"fill"}' > </div> </a> </li> <li> <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/agencyb/" target="_blank"  > <div data-image-info='{"imageData":{"type":"Image","id":"dataItem-ijxtrrjj","metaData":{"pageId":"masterPage","isPreset":false,"schemaVersion":"2.0","isHidden":false},"title":"Black Pinterest Icon","uri":"8f6f59264a094af0b46e9f6c77dff83e.png","width":200,"height":200,"alt":"Black Pinterest Icon","link":{"type":"ExternalLink","id":"dataItem-ikg674xm","metaData":{"pageId":"masterPage","isPreset":false,"schemaVersion":"1.0","isHidden":false},"url":"https://www.pinterest.com/agencyb/","target":"_blank"}},"displayMode":"fill"}' > </div> </a> </li> <li> <a href="http://www.twitter.com/lubecka" target="_blank"  > <div data-image-info='{"imageData":{"type":"Image","id":"dataItem-ifp3554u","metaData":{"pageId":"masterPage","isPreset":false,"schemaVersion":"2.0","isHidden":false},"title":"Black Twitter Icon","uri":"c7d035ba85f6486680c2facedecdcf4d.png","description":"","width":200,"height":200,"alt":"Black Twitter Icon","link":{"type":"ExternalLink","id":"dataItem-ifp3554u1","metaData":{"pageId":"masterPage","isPreset":false,"schemaVersion":"1.0","isHidden":false},"url":"http://www.twitter.com/lubecka","target":"_blank"}},"displayMode":"fill"}' > </div> </a> </li> <li> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">
<html>
```

Comment: Does your final output always look like this `<li>some text</li>` or do these tags vary?

Comment: tags will be different @JackFleeting, could also be `div`, `span`, etc

Comment: I've edited the question to further clarify the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the names of the "data attributes" always start with "data-", you can remove them like this:

```
for el in tree.xpath("//*"):
    for attr in el.attrib:
        if attr.startswith("data-"):
            el.attrib.pop(attr)
```

Comment: +1 You could also change your first xpath to `//*[@*[starts-with(name(),'data-')]]` to only process elements that have attributes that start with `data-`.

Comment: great thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can clear the attributes like this

```
import re
def strip_attribute(data):
    p = re.compile('data-[^=]*="[^"]*"')
    print(p)
    return p.sub('', data)
print(strip_attribute('with attribute'))
```

Comment: Thanks, @kubarik, however it won't work for the updated html example I made in the question

Comment: @kurupt_89, not sure, but maybe so: `(data-[^=]*=(').*?(')+)|(data-[^=]*=(").*?(")+)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
from lxml import etree

code = """
 <html>
   <ul>
    <li data-i="sdfdsf">something</li>
    <li data-i="dsfd">something</li>
  </ul>
    <p data-para="cvcv">content</p> 
</html>

"""

xml = etree.XML(code)
elements = list(xml.iter())
for element in elements:
   if len(element.text.strip())>0:
      print('<'+element.tag+'>'+element.text+'</'+element.tag+'>')
```

Output:

```
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<p>content</p>
```